# what is the meaning of relative source Ancestor Type?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

here ,i know that relative source use as getting value with respect to the other but i can not get meaning of the `RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}`

```
Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemOptions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}
```

plz explain it .i think it is a trivial .u can explain  me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells WPF to walk up the tree of 'parents' from the current control andfind the first one of type UserControl.  In this case, the binding is to that ItemOptions property of that usercontrol's DataContext